# Join two select statement from one table

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql

i have a table named attendance with 2 attributes (id, remarks). i want to display the tally of absence or late per id from the attendance table.

```
Attendance Table
|ID         | Remarks       |
=============================
|1          | Absent        |
|1          | Late          |
|2          | Absent        |
|2          | Absent        |
|3          | Late          |

Sample Output
|ID         | Absent   | Late    |
==================================
|1          | 1        | 1       |
|2          | 2        |         |
|3          |          | 1       |
```

currently, i can only output 2 columns, (ID and Absent) or (ID and Late) using this code:

```
SELECT id, count(remarks) AS Absent 
FROM attendance 
WHERE remarks = 'Absent' 
GROUP BY id;
```

i can't display absent and late column simultaneously.. please help. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is basically a `PIVOT`. If you do not have access to a `PIVOT` function then, you can replicate it with an aggregate function and a `CASE` statement:

```
select id,
  sum(case when remarks = 'Absent' then 1 else 0 end) Absent,
  sum(case when remarks = 'Late' then 1 else 0 end) Late
from attendance
group by id
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e48c1/1)

Or you can use `COUNT()`:

```
select id,
  count(case when remarks = 'Absent' then 1 else null end) Absent,
  count(case when remarks = 'Late' then 1 else null end) Late
from attendance
group by id;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e48c1/3)

Answer (score 0):

Use a `SUM(CASE)` construct to separate the `Absent` and `Late`.  For each one, the CASE returns a 1 or 0 if the value is matched, and then those are added up via the aggregate `SUM()` giving the total number. The concept at work here is known as a [pivot table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pivot_table).

```
SELECT
  id,
  SUM(CASE WHEN Remarks = 'Absent' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Absent,
  SUM(CASE WHEN Remarks = 'Late' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Late
FROM
  attendance
GROUP BY id
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
 SELECT id, 
     Sum (Case remarks When 'Absent' Then 1 End) Absent,
     Sum (Case remarks When 'Late' Then 1 End) Late
 FROM attendance 
 GROUP BY id;
```